# VBScript to change top node

Tags: xml, vbscript, rename, xmlnode

I have an xml file that gets automatically exported, but comes with a wrong node/element. It looks as follows when exported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StraightTableBox>
 <order>
  <ordernr>10000</ordernr>
  <trackingcode>JVGL0123456789101112</trackingcode>
  <trackingurl>http://www.dhl-tracknet.nl/cgi-bin-al/UFA100/NL/?type=U&amp;#38;zoekveld=JVGL0123456789101112</trackingurl>
 </order>
 <order>
  <ordernr>20000</ordernr>
  <trackingcode>JVGL0123456789101113</trackingcode>
  <trackingurl>http://www.dhl-tracknet.nl/cgi-bin-al/UFA100/NL/?type=U&amp;#38;zoekveld=JVGL0123456789101113</trackingurl>
 </order>
 <order>
  <ordernr>30000</ordernr>
  <trackingcode>JVGL0123456789101114</trackingcode>
  <trackingurl>http://www.dhl-tracknet.nl/cgi-bin-al/UFA100/NL/?type=U&amp;#38;zoekveld=JVGL0123456789101114</trackingurl>
 </order>
 <order>
  <ordernr>40000</ordernr>
  <trackingcode>JVGL0123456789101115</trackingcode>
  <trackingurl>http://www.dhl-tracknet.nl/cgi-bin-al/UFA100/NL/?type=U&amp;#38;zoekveld=JVGL0123456789101115</trackingurl>
 </order>
</StraightTableBox>
```

Now I need to change the  and  into  and  via a VBScript.

So far I manage to open the document, select the node it concerns (I think at least) and save the edited document. But changing the name of the node doesn't work.

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.load "H:\Scripts\Tracktrace.xml"

'Locate the desired node
'Note the use of XPATH instead of looping over all the child nodes
Set nNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("StraightTableBox")

'Save the xml document with the new node.
strResult = xmldoc.save("TracktraceEdited.xml")
```

How can I change the node into what I require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't change the .tagName, and string ops may cause problems (utf-8 encoding) later, you need to create a new element "orders", append the children of the original documentElement, and 'replace' that with the new node. In code (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1559010/603855)):

```
  Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\order-1.xml")
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.load sFSpec

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     Dim ndDE : Set ndDE = objMSXML.createElement("orders")
     Dim ndO
     For Each ndO In objMSXML.documentElement.childNodes
         ndDE.appendChild ndO
     Next
     Set objMSXML.documentElement = ndDE
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.xml
     objMSXML.save Replace(sFSpec, "-1", "-2")
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

**Update wrt comment:**

I usually start my scripts with:

```
Option Explicit
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

When I tried to make my test script 'stand alone', I messed up the names. Sorry. So use:

```
Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\order-1.xml")
```

Comment: I tried running the above script where I changed just the goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\order-1.xml") to the location my document is. But I get an error: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/30wb985/8 And I don't know what goes wrong when I tried to google the error.

Comment: Thanks that works! I do have another question though regarding the same document. The xml gets automatically exported to a location which I can set with oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("location") as I understand now :). Now I don't really need to see the result as popup so I commented WScript.Echo objMSXML.xml out. Then at the part to save the document it changes the extension of -1 to -2. Can I make it that it save it under a standard new name at another location or even ftp?

Comment: @LeQuestione - why don't you read about .save here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?

Comment: Thank you, works as I want. Only been using this for 1 day! So my apologies for the question :-)